# Unable to add product offer to inventory in Amazon SP API

Tags: node.js, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to write some code in Node.js to manage my Amazon Seller marketplace inventory.
Currently i manage inventory by manually submitting a CSV file with all products offers (CD, DVD, records).

I tried using amazon SP API, but with no success.

Here is an example request:

```
body: {"productType":"PRODUCT","product_type":"PRODUCT","requirements":"LISTING_OFFER_ONLY","attributes":{"condition_type":[{"value":"used_acceptable","marketplace_id":"APJ6JRA9NG5V4"}]},"offers":[{"marketplaceId":"APJ6JRA9NG5V4","offerType":"B2C","price":{"currencyCode":"EUR","amount":20.99}}]}



var config = {
    method: 'PUT',
    url: `https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/A23B5NP94ZWC8W/${sku}?marketplaceIds=${marketplaceIds}&issueLocale=en_US`,
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'x-amz-access-token': access_token,
        'X-Amz-Date': awssign.headers["X-Amz-Date"],
        'Authorization': `${awssign.headers.Authorization}`,
        "Content-Type":'application/json'
    },
    data: body
    
};

await axios(config)
```

but i receive the following errors:

```
"sku": "AAACD100249",
            "status": "INVALID",
    "submissionId": "b3e9b60a2e0c41ad804d17795b0f5f41",
    "issues": [
        {
            "code": "90220",
            "message": "'merchant_suggested_asin' is required but not supplied.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "attributeNames": [
                "merchant_suggested_asin"
            ]
        },
        {
            "code": "90220",
            "message": "'externally_assigned_product_identifier' is required but not supplied.",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "attributeNames": [
                "externally_assigned_product_identifier"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The product is existing, also ASIN is valid. I do not need to create a "new" produt, but only an offer for this one.

Amazon documentation https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-use-case-guide is not useful.

What parameters are missing?
Is it the correct way? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by adding  merchant_suggested_asin, externally_assigned_product_identifier, and condition_type in body

```
{
    "productType": "PRODUCT",
    "product_type": "PRODUCT",
    "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
    "attributes": {
        "condition_type": [
            {
                "value": "used_acceptable",
                "marketplace_id": "APJ6JRA9NG5V4"
            }
        ]
    },
    "offers": [
        {
            "marketplaceId": "APJ6JRA9NG5V4",
            "offerType": "B2C",
            "price": {
                "currencyCode": "EUR",
                "amount": 20.99
            }
        }
    ],
    "merchant_suggested_asin": [
        {
            "value": "WPID|ASIN"
        }
    ],
    "externally_assigned_product_identifier": [
        {
            "value": "WPID|ASIN"
        }
    ],
    "condition_type": [
        {
            "value": "new_new",
            "marketplace_id": "APJ6JRA9NG5V4"     
        }
    ]
}
```

you can get the WPID|ASIN in your manage inventory under the Product Name column or you are getting this in your get product API

Note: add condition_type only if shows the required error for condition_type